# Uploading a photo with Flickr

Tags: php, photo, flickr

I just started working with the Flickr API today and I have a question:

If I allow a person to upload a photo to my website and then in order for me not to store it on my small local server, how can I just upload that photo to Flickr using the PHP Flickr API?

That should be a pretty common use case, correct?  I use PHP.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flickr Upload API:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Simple php script to upload pics on flickr
http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157621716056865/

Maybe this will point you in the right direction since depending on what you want to do with your files after you upload them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the documentation for the [API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html).  I've worked with it in the past, you don't need to download the image yourself you upload it and send it straight to Flickr.